# Why are you voting to close this question?

Tags: discussion

[How to choose a right 3D printer filament type?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-to-choose-a-right-3d-printer-filament-type)

I mean, this is usefull question. Why are you guys voting for close? It's not too broad, I formated it to be direct on topic.

Thanks afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question. Any chance for reopen? http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/410/difference-between-pla-and-abs

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question can be considered "too broad" because you basically ask for the pros, cons and similarities of *every* filament that can be 3D-printed.

You last paragraph is a better question, since you here ask *how* to find the right filament for your cause. If that is really what you want to ask, you could try putting more emphasis on that specific question.

If what you actually want to know is what filament you should use for one *specific* application - for instance for a part that need to withstand physical stress - try asking about that instead.

In general, it can often be better to ask a question with a specific scenario - even a constructed case - than asking general questions.

Also, remember to always try getting your title as specific as possible, since that is the first impression users will get when the read your post!

Comment: Yes, essentially the author is inviting a long discussion about a broad topic. Even if someone could come up with a summary of the different filament types (nothing necessarily *wrong* with that), it doesn't actually answer a question in any *definitive* way. That's why Stack Exchange is often portrayed as "ask a question about a problem you actually have right now."

Comment: So, has someone edit suggestion?

Comment: @JosipIvic, I believe this answer points out a few alternatives. The actual "new" question is up to you to find. :)

Comment: well, I don't want that question to be closed.

Comment: @JosipIvic, in that case, I suggest you update the question (reformulate it so that it has to be answered very specifically), and then request for it to be reopened!

Comment: I've edited it. Maybe now?

Comment: I now agree that it is a much better question. It is still fairly generic, but also possible to answer in a Q&A format. However, this exact same question has in fact already been raised before. It is therefore very well possible that your edit will be marked as a *duplicate* instead! :-) 

http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-is-pla-different-from-abs-material

Comment: So my question to you then is: could you try to rephrase it to not be a duplicate of the question linked above, perhaps by making the question even more application specific? Or, on the other hand, why do you think the question linked does not answer your edited question? Such things might be worth specifying in your question as well! :-)